# Writing a generalized function for both strings and lists in python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

So i'm green as grass and learning programming from [How to think like a computer scientist: Learn python 3](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/lists.html). I'm able to answer the question (see below) but fear i'm missing the lesson.

Write a function (called insert_at_end) that will pass (return the bold given the two arguments before) for all three:

```
test(insert_at_end(5, [1, 3, 4, 6]), **[1, 3, 4, 6, 5]**)
test(insert_at_end('x', 'abc'),  **'abcx'**)
test(insert_at_end(5, (1, 3, 4, 6)), **(1, 3, 4, 6, 5)**)
```

The book gives this hint:"These exercises illustrate nicely that the sequence abstraction is general, (**because slicing, indexing, and concatenation** are so general), so it is possible to write general functions that work over all sequence types.".

This version doesn't have solutions on-line (that i could find) but in I found someone's answers to a previous version of the text (for python 2.7) and they did it this way:

```
def encapsulate(val, seq):
    if type(seq) == type(""):
        return str(val)
    if type(seq) == type([]):
        return [val]
    return (val,)

def insert_at_end(val, seq): 
    return seq + encapsulate(val, seq)
```

Which seems to be solving the question by distinguishing between lists and strings... going against the hint.  So how about it Is there a way to answer the question (and about 10 more similar ones) without distinguishing? i.e not using "type()"

Comment: I don't think you will learn anything useful from trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* a solution but rather an explanation why a truly elegant solution does not look possible.

- `+` concatenates sequences, but only sequences of same type.
- values passed as first argument to `insert_at_end` are 'scalar', so you have to convert them to the sequence type that the second argument has.
- to do that, you cannot simply call a sequence constructor with a scalar argument and create a one-item sequence of that type: `tuple(1)` does not work.
- `str` works differently than other sequence types: `tuple(["a"])` is `("a",)`, `list(["a"])` is `["a"]`, but `str(["a"]))` is `"['a']"` and not `"a"`.

This renders `+` useless in this situation, even though you can easily construct a sequence of  given type cleanly, without `instanceof`, just by using `type()`.

You can't use slice assignment, too, since only lists are mutable.

In this situation, the solution by @Hamish looks cleanest.

Comment: Hamish's solution is fairly clean, but I think it goes badly wrong if you try to insert a multi character string at the end of a list of strings.

Comment: @Duncan: well, with lists, you can add a nested list, but there's no such thing as a nested string. To properly prevent it you either need to explicitly check for `str` (which defeats the purpose) or have a static type system powerful enough to forbid nested lists (which takes a different language than Python).

Comment: @9000 Excellent Thank you, essential (more then a specific answer ) i was looking to confirm that as you put it "a elegant solution doesn't not look possible". I was worried i was missing an underlying concept that might later hound me.

Answer (score 3):

My best effort:

```
def insert_at_end(val, seq):
    t = type(seq)
    try:
        return seq + t(val)
    except TypeError:
        return seq + t([val])
```

This will attempt to create the sequence of `type(seq)` and if `val` is not iterable produces a list and concatenates.

Comment: `test(insert_at_end('xyz', ['abc']),  **['abc','xyz']**)` wouldn't pass.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the example isn't symetric, meaning that it asks the reader handle two different cases:

- int, list
- str, str

In my opinion, the exercise should ask to implement this:

- list, list: insert_at_end([5], [1, 3, 4, 6])
- str, str: insert_at_end('x', 'abc')

In this case, the reader has to work only with two parameters that use the same sequence type and the hint would make much more sense.

Comment: I don't agree - it's not the sequence type that's a problem - it's whether the new value is iterable or not.

Comment: I think, the whole problem is that the str (or unicode) work differently than list, tuple or whatever. Otherwise str(['a', 'b', 'c']) would produce 'abc' and not "['a', 'b', 'c']"...

Answer (score 1):

That problem is one of a long list and the hint applies to all of them. I think it is reasonable that, having written the `encapsulate` function which can be re-used for things like `insert_at_front`, the rest of the implementation is type agnostic.

However, I think a better implementation of `encapsulate` might be:

```
def encapsulate(val, seq):
    if isinstance(seq, basestring):
        return val
    return type(seq)([val])
```

which handles a wider range of types with less code.

Comment: Upside: this solution works. Downside: it's not a nice type-agnostic solution that uses the common interface of sequences; instead, it special-cases some magical class.

Comment: @9000, strings often need to be special cased, they are the only sequence that only contain objects of the same type as themselves and that messes up a lot of otherwise clean duck typed code. Otherwise it handles `list`, `tuple`, their subclasses and any other sequence that follows the general model that it can be constructed from a list.

Comment: yes, strings need to be special-cased, and this is the grim truth that prevents this problem from having an elegant type-agnostic, fully interface-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with this question (in Python 2.7, I'm testing 3.2 right now to verify) is that two of the possible input types for `seq` are immutable, and you're expected to return the same type as was passed in.  For strings, this is less of an issue, because you could do this:

```
return seq + char
```

As that will return a new string that's the concatenation of the input sequence and the appended character, but that doesn't work for lists or tuples.  You can only concatenate a list to a list or a tuple to a tuple.  If you wanted to avoid "type" checking, you could get there with something like this:

```
if hasattr(seq, 'append'): # List input.
  seq.append(char)
elif hasattr(seq, 'strip'): # String input.
  seq = seq + char
else: # Tuple
  seq = seq + (char,)

return seq
```

That's really not much different from actually checking types, but it does avoid using the `type` function directly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution still requires some separate code for strings as opposed to lists/tuples, but it is more concise and doesn't do any checking for specific types.

```
def insert_at_end(val, seq):
    try:
        return seq + val
    except TypeError:   # unsupported operand type(s) for +
        return seq + type(seq)([val])
```

Comment: how about: assert insert_at_end(['val'], ['seq']) == ['seq', ['val']] ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is nearer the answer:

```
def genappend(x, s):
    if isinstance(s, basestring):
        t = s[0:0].join
    else:
        t = type(s)
    lst = list(s)
    lst.append(x)
    return t(lst)

print genappend(5, [1,2,3,4])    
print genappend(5, (1,2,3,4))
print genappend('5', '1234')
```

There could also be completely user-defined sequence types. They will also work as long as convertable to and from a list. This also works:

```
print genappend('5', set('1234'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the point is if `item` is iterable or not.

So my solution would be this:

```
def iterate(seq, item):
    for i in seq:
        yield i
    yield item

def insert_at_end(seq, item):
    if hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
        return seq + item
    else:
        return type(seq)(iterate(seq, item))
```

Example:

```
>>> insert_at_end('abc', 'x')
'abcx'
>>> insert_at_end([1, 2, 4, 6], 5)
[1, 2, 4, 6, 5]
>>> insert_at_end((1, 2, 4, 6), 5)
(1, 2, 4, 6, 5)
```

Since `insert_at_end` can handle iterable and not, works fine even with:

```
>>> insert_at_end('abc', 'xyz')
'abcxyz'
>>> insert_at_end([1, 2, 4, 6], [5, 7])
[1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7]
>>> insert_at_end((1, 2, 4, 6), (5, 7))
(1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7)
```

Comment: This is plain wrong. insert_at_end([1, 2, 4, 6], [5]) should be [1, 2, 4, 6, [5]] by all logic.

Comment: @RomanSusi: If you want to handle string and list in the same way, I would say that that it's not what I'd expect. On the other hand by common sense I would agree with you; so I'm the first to be a little a confused and I wont argue too much because it seems that the author of the exercise had his own logic too...

Answer (score -1):

While encapsulate relies on the type, the code directly in insert_at_end does not, and relies on + meaning related things for all 3 types, and so in that sense, fits in with the hint.

Comment: There must be a nicer answer. The answer could probably use type, but not particular types.

Comment: You can't just throw the offending code into a different function and call it a win! :D

Comment: I'd be interested to see that, too -- but I haven't seen anyone suggest one yet.